# Hit by pitch or strike?

Tags: baseball

If a pitch hits a batter in the strike zone, it is my understanding that it is a strike.  What if a pitch nicks the strike zone say on the low and inside edge, but hits the batters ankle out of the strike zone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rule 5.05(2)b](https://content.mlb.com/documents/2/2/4/305750224/2019_Official_Baseball_Rules_FINAL_.pdf)

If a batter is struck with a pitch **while it is in the strike zone**, it should be a strike. Otherwise, it is a ball or a HBP, depending on if the batter tried to get out the way.